# How do I use external CSS in an HTML document in VSC?

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code

I'm practicing using HTML in VSC. I want to use external CSS, since I've already figured out inline CSS and internal CSS. However, when I try to use external CSS, the page doesn't change.

I've tried different documents, and I've tried copying the code from documents that already work. I've tried typing the code into different spots etc. But nothing seems to work.

Any ideas why this might be happening? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lScHk.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipLWL.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRiFt.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to save both the files with .html or .htm extension for html file and .css for css file

Second the path of the css must be correct if both the html and css path are on same directory then code this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css">
```

I think it works if not can you post the screenshot of the directory you are working and the css and html file

Thank You!!!